# Where is msvcp90d.dll supposed to come from?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

What is the story with the VC debug CRT?  where is it supposed to come from?

in particular, on my machine, running both VS2008 and VS2010 I dont have the amd64 version installed in c:\windows\winsxs?

reading about this on the internet has been very confusing,  I feel that everyone is hacking around, copying bits to C:\windows\system32, etc.

Where am I suppose to be getting the debug CRT and how do I correctly install it?  I see the binaries were copied to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist during the VS install.

now what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft don't want you to put the Debug CRT DLL on end user machines so they don't provide an installer for it.

Quote from [the VC2005 doc on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618%28VS.80%29.aspx) Which I assume still applies to 2008 (emphasis is mine):

> Debug versions of an application are
>   not redistributable and **none of the
>   debug versions of the various Visual
>   C++ dynamic-link libraries (DLLs) are
>   redistributable**. Debug versions of an
>   application and Visual C++ libraries
>   can only be deployed to another
>   computer internal to your development
>   site for the sole purpose of debugging
>   and testing your application on a
>   computer that does not have Visual C++
>   2005 installed.

If you need to test a debug build of you application on another machines you still can:

- Copy the DLL and manifest from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist` into your application directory
- Include the Microsoft_VC90_DebugCRT_x86.msm merge module as part of your own installer.

Comment: no kidding?  it's not that I dont believe you but could you provide a reference?  how are you sure?

Comment: @Chris Gray I have edited my post. I can't find a reference for vc9 unfortunately. Maybe things have changed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the first option above - copying the DLLs and Manifest from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist into my application directory

The SxS system on my test machine kept complaining (via sxstrace) that the version numbers were not correct.

Interad, I found a more recent versions of the manifest in c:\Windows\winsxs\Manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc90.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_4ec74c6b3093419c.manifest and copied this to Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.manifest in the test application directory.